# Integrate Firebase Cloud Messaging with custom authentication in Browser

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a use case where I need to have FCM messages sent only if the user is logged in to my website. There is an issue where if Google delays the sending of the message and a different user logs into the same machine, then they may be shown the notification meant for the first user. Is there any support to attach custom authentication by Google when the message is actually received by Chrome.

Comment: you have an app right?

Comment: No I'm integrating FCM on my website.